# Konig's lemma proof

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

[Konig's lemma](https://i.gyazo.com/c70169101caec6c4ec7a0ec26494fe97.png)

In this proof of Konig's lemma taken from Kaye's book "The mathematics of logic: A guide to completeness theorems and their applications", I am having a lot of trouble understanding the "We are going to find a sequence of $s(n)$ of elements of $T$ such that..." portion. We are trying to find a sequence $s(n)$ such that it satisfies the given properties. Drawing attention to the first property, "$s(n)$ has length $n$", am I correct in saying these are not the same $n$ in that one is a dummy variable and the other is of course the length of the sequence hence $s(n) = (s(0),s(1),...,s(n-1))$? If this is the case, how is it that we can talk about $s(n+1)$ where $n+1$ is supposedly the next element of the sequence consisting of only $n$ terms as I have described? Note that the half-arrow in the subsequent property is a restriction operator taking the first $n$ elements of the sequence $s(n+1)$ as is shown in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$ in $s(n)$ and the length of the sequence most definitely **are** the same $n$. For each $n\in\omega$, $s(n)$ is both an element of $T$ and a sequence of zeroes and ones of length $n$. In particular, for any given $n$, $s(n+1)$ is an element of $T$ that is a sequence of $n+1$ zeroes and ones. If $s(n+1)=\langle b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n\rangle$, then $s(n+1)\upharpoonright n=\langle b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_{n-1}\rangle$.

It might have been clearer if the author had written this:

> We are going to find a sequence $\langle s(n):n\in\omega\rangle$ of elements of $T$ such that for each $n\in\omega$,
>
> - $s(n)$ has length $n$,
> - $s(n)=s(n+1)\upharpoonright n$, and
> - the tree $T_{s(n)}$ below $s(n)$ is infinite.